# Configuring secure web socket for nginx? System.Net.WebSocket for server in C#

Tags: nginx

Any idea about configuring secure web socket?
I have used System.Net.WebSocket for server in C#. I wanted to configure nginx for this. WebSocket will listen to https://localhost:9000. What will be settings required for it in nginx configuration file.

Answer (score 0):

From reading your question I guess you are asking for an nginx vhost configuration example for an https upstream proxy.

Here's such a configuration example:

```
server {
    listen 443;
    listen [::]:443;
    server_name www.example.com;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header     Host      $host;
        proxy_set_header     X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_pass           https://localhost:9000;

        proxy_ssl_certificate         /etc/nginx/client.pem;
        proxy_ssl_certificate_key     /etc/nginx/client.key
        proxy_ssl_protocols           TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
        proxy_ssl_ciphers             HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
        proxy_ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/nginx/trusted_ca_cert.crt;

        proxy_ssl_verify        on;
        proxy_ssl_verify_depth  2;
        proxy_ssl_session_reuse on;
    }

}
```

And maybe you would also like to have a redirect for http -> https:

```
server {
   listen 80;
   listen [::]:80;
   server_name www.example.com;
   return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}
```

For more please see [NGINX: securing http traffic to upstream servers](https://www.nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/nginx-https-upstreams/) and

Comment: what would the c# code look like? ie what are the passed credentials?

Comment: for instance, currently in c#: _server = new WebSocketServer("wss://0.0.0.0:8200/MessageRelayer")
{
    Certificate = new X509Certificate2(PfxFileName, SslPassword),
    RestartAfterListenError = true
};